# iOS rebuild GLES Context

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, opengl-es

In order to test my app for GLES2/3 compatibility I'm trying to delete and rebuild the GLES context at runtime. But whatever I do I always get a blank screen and a GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION at glClear

To delete/rebuild the context Im using this code in the GLKview drawInRect:

```
// Destroy the context
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == self.context)
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
self.context = nil;


// Rebuild the context
switch( profile )
{
    case 20:
    {
        self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
        break;
    }

    case 30:
    {
        self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3];
        break;
    }
}

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
```

Right after this code Im calling glClear and get the error described above and the screen just stay black... No other error is generated... Is there anything that Im missing here?

Comment: A frame buffer? You can not simply create a new context and continue with drawing, presenting the buffer. The context is the object that contains all the data associated with the openGL. What you can try is create the second context with the share group from the first one and then delete the first context.

Comment: Correct me if Im wrong but Im pretty sure that you cannot share the data of an OpenGLES2 and OpenGL3 context right?

Comment: Well, if you are sure about that then I see no other way but to recreate ALL the resources on the GPU after you switch the context.

Comment: By default resources are not shared between two contexts. There is a way to create a shared context for the purpose of only loading resource on a different thread but I don't think you can have two context that both render and share resources. Not sure though. You can tell when you create texture resources and two different textures might use the same ID on different contexts.